# Reading Terminal Inputs and Outputs of Another Terminal Using Python

Tags: python, bash, cmd, terminal

Suppose I am running a python script in terminal A. I also have terminal B where I type in commands and get output. I would like for my python script in terminal A to be able to read the commands that have been typed in terminal B and their outputs. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: I don't know what your needs are, but if it;s to do something simple, just write things to a text file and read/write from it. (Don't forget to open and close it)

Comment: I need the inputs and outputs in real time and I do not have control over them so I can't write them to a text file

Comment: What OS? You have bash and cmd tags, are you on Windows or something else? Also, do you control both scripts (the one for terminal A and the one for B)?

Comment: If you are on Linux, then `script -f` can be useful, but is non-standard.  See the example on `man script`.

Comment: in case your python is running the second command with subprocess.popen, you could read its output using pipe. but w/o running in other terminal

Comment: Note that tag [tag:cmd] refers to the Windows command prompt; so please adapt the tags accordingly!

Comment: Assuming the cmd tag means the OP is interested in Windows, it's possible to attach to the console of another process and read the screen buffer (e.g. via `ReadConsoleOutputCharacter`), but only if it's in the same session and the caller is granted sufficient access by the security descriptor of the conhost.exe instance, including being at the same integrity level or higher (e.g. a UAC restricted token isn't granted access to an elevated console).